# Location strategy deletes *.html from URL

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have an  issue with my app.

I am getting ready to release stable version, and my live version files and directories schema on the server will look like this:

```
--index.html
--services.html
--app/
----app.html (root of angular2 app)
----other files
```

My issue is, that when I am directing to:

http://localhost:5000/app/app.html

it changes the url to:

http://localhost:5000/#/main

My location strategy so far is `HashLocationStrategy`.

How can I fix that, so the url persists to be:

http://localhost:5000/app/app.html#/main

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

I've deletedthe `HashLocationStrategy`, and added the following:

```
{provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/app/app.html'}
```

Which now redirects me to:

http://localhost:5000/app/app.html/main

However, when I reload the page like this, it wont find the webpage (I guess it needs hash instead of slash there..)

Comment: What happens if you add <base href="/app/app.html"> to your html page?

Comment: It pretty much ruins the whole page, as all of the static files (css etc) are loaded from the root of the server file path.

Comment: Do you use relative paths for these?

Comment: No, I use absolute: for example: <script src="assets/vendor/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: That's a relative path. Absolute paths start with a /. Where is the assets directory located?

Comment: The assets directory is placed in the same folder as the index.html file.

Comment: Then use <script src="/assets/vendor/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: "It pretty much ruins the whole page, as all of the static files (css etc) are loaded from the root of the server file path" - then you need to configure your server to handle that properly.